# \FPeval ceil results in "multiple values"

Tags: errors, fp

`\FPeval` returns a multiple values error when using `ceil` or `floor`, but not `trunc` or `round`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\first}{78}
\newcommand{\second}{12}
\FPeval{\result}{ceil(\first / \second, 2)}

\result

\end{document}
```

The error is: "FP error: Evaluation results in multiple values!." Replacing `ceil` with `round` works without errors.

Comment: I cannot answer the question, but I can confirm that the error also appears when compiled using `lualatex`, and that the `graphicx` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It turns out I was reading the documentation for xfp and not fp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fp`](//ctan.org/pkg/fp) doesn't provide the `ceil` nor `floor` operator with `\FPeval`, only `round` and `trunc` (see the [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/fp)). Regardless, it's more convenient to use [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) (should form part of any default LaTeX installation):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{xfp} % Should form part of any default LaTeX installation
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\first}{78}%
\newcommand{\second}{12}%
\FPeval{\result}{round((\first) / (\second), 2)}

\result

\fpeval{ceil(\first / \second, 2)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to save the result of \fpeval into a variable like \FPeval{\result}{<expression>}?

Comment: @nvrain: Yes. For example, `\edef\result{\fpeval{<expression>}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `fp` package provides neither floor nor ceiling functions. There are `round` and `trunc` (and `clip` that removes trailing zeros). It's quite puzzling that these functions have not been implemented, actually.

Anyway, the official syntax for `round` and `trunc` is not with a comma:
`round(3.14159:2)` would return `3.14`. But it turns out that commas can be used as well.

Implementing floor and ceiling in `fp` should not be that hard, but there's something better available, which *has* the functions.

With no package at all, provided your LaTeX is not more than a couple of years old, you can do

```
\fpeval{ceil(\first/\second,2)}
```

and get `6.5`. This is fully expandable, so it can be used even in something like

```
\fpeval{ceil(\first/\second,2)}\mylen
```

where `\mylen` is some length parameter defined with `\newlength`. Thus you shouldn't need to store the result in macros.

You can do it, of course, but I'd not perpetuate the bad practice of not checking about definedness of the commands we want to use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definefp}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \fp_new:c { l_nvrain_fp_##1_fp }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfp}{mm}
 {
  \fp_set:cn { l_nvrain_fp_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefp}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_nvrain_fp_#1_fp }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definefp{raw,result}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\first}{78}
\newcommand{\second}{11}% to make the thing more interesting

\setfp{raw}{\first/\second}
\setfp{result}{ceil(\first/\second,2)}

Raw: \usefp{raw}

Result: \usefp{result}

\end{document}
```

This way, you're sure that you don't clobber existing commands, which can very well happen with `\FPeval` that never checks about the name of the command it will store the result in.

You can employ `\usefp` in any place where a floating point number is expected, even in the second argument to `\setfp` or, in general, in the argument of `\fpeval`.

[image]